# Libgdx FileHandle readString() not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I have created a text file called useraccounts.txt. All i want to do
is read the file using the filehandle class but I always get this
exception

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Cannot open a stream to a
>   directory: useraccounts.txt (Local)

Here is my code:

```
FileHande accountsFile = Gdx.files.local("useraccounts.txt");
String text = accountsFile.readString();
```

An explanation is appreciated!

Comment: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.java), it only throws this exception if it thinks the file is a directory. Is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration, I found out that I had made a folder the same name with the text file by mistake!! After deleting the folder all works fine, thank you for replying!

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it should be **local()** actually not internal? - you should notice where do you exactly keep your file.

You can read something more about FileHandle obtaining here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#obtaining-filehandles

Regards,
Michał

Comment: with my experience with libgdx i will also put my bet that it should be internal.

Comment: Both internal and local throw the same error. I'm using local because I need write access too.

Comment: Ok, then check if you have a directory named same that file? If so - try to change directory name